# No OUTPUT from Jupyter Notebook. NO Error Shown

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tornado, jupyter-irkernel

I am running a Jupyter notebook but I do not get any output or error telling me if something is wrong. I have tried installing tornado as some other threads have suggested as well as the command `pip install notebook --upgrade`

While I do not think there is a problem with my code here it is.

Any help is truly appreciated.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2
from glob import glob

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam 

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

if __name__=="_main_": 
    path="dog-breed-identification/"
    train_path = os.path.join(path, "train/*")
    train_path = os.path.join(path, "test/*")
    train_path = os.path.join(path, "labels.csv")

labels_df = pd.read_csv(labels_path)

#name of column in csv
breed = labels_df["breed"].unique()
print("Number of Breed: ", len(breed))
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, if I delete

```
if __name__=="_main_":
```

I get an output